# Get emitted events of a a smart contract function using infura

Tags: web3js, etherscan, ethereumjs, infura

I have used infura in my App.js to connect to the kovan network. Then I am creating an instance of the smart contract deployed on that network. Then I am calling a function on that smart contract which emits an event.

This returns a transaction hash but I want to access the event details emitted by that smart contract function. I thought I might use that transaction hash on kovan etherscan site and get the event details emitted but it didnot work. How do I access them?

I have sent a signed transaction through infura:

```
    const Tx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction

    // connect to Infura node
    const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("//kovan infura key"));

    // the address that will send the test transaction
    const addressFrom = '//myaccountaddress'
    const privKey = '//my key'

    // the destination address
    const addressTo = '//contractaddress'

    function sendSigned(txData,cb) {
      const privateKey = new Buffer.from("privateKey", 'hex')
      const transaction = new Tx(txData)
      transaction.sign(privateKey)
      const serializedTx = transaction.serialize().toString('hex')
      web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction('0x' + serializedTx,cb)
    }

    const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(Contract.abi,Contract.address, {from: addressFrom,gasLimit: 3000000});
    const contractFunction = contract.methods.getDetails(0);

    const functionAbi = contractFunction.encodeABI();

    // get the number of transactions sent so far so we can create a fresh nonce
    web3.eth.getTransactionCount(addressFrom).then(txCount => {

      // construct the transaction data
      const txData = {
        nonce: web3.utils.toHex(txCount),
        gasLimit: web3.utils.toHex(25000),
        gasPrice: web3.utils.toHex(10e12), // 10 Gwei
        to: addressTo,
        from: addressFrom,
        data: functionAbi
      }

      // fire away!
       sendSigned(txData, function(err, result) {
      if (err) return console.log('error', err)
      console.log('sent', result)
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logs are included in the [transaction receipt](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#gettransactionreceipt).

Unless you use some wrapper around the contract to get the logs they will be encoded. Then you will have to use something like [web3.api.abi.decodeLog](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth-abi.html#decodelog).

Comment: can you please explain in little bit more detail that what is happening over here and what exactly I need to do?

Comment: @ShivamRaina From web3 [sendSignedTransaction documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#sendsignedtransaction) the callback returns the transaction hash, it doesn't wait for the transaction to be mined. You have to use the [`on('receipt', ..)`](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.6/web3-eth.html#eth-sendtransaction-return). Etherscan without a contract being verified it will not process events, also in kovan txs processing might get delayed because it is a testnet.